# stack remote download

Tags: support, app

The application is not present on Google Play and there is no download link. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application is no longer under active development and is abandoned. For more details, see [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.